# why i am getting Input path E:/New does not exist?

Tags: mapreduce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKYHc.png)
am trying to run mapreduce code using spyder but it gives me this error and says Input path E:/New does not exist! . both the code file and the data file r in the same folder so what can i do ?

Comment: Please improve your question. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

you are reading the data/file from **E:/New folder/u.data** location, there is SPACE in folder Name (i.e. E:/New folder)

and that is why you are getting Input path E:/New does not exist!

Any program (in any language) expects SPACE-seperated list of arguments, here you are passing the valid path but internally path splits into multiple arguments.